# Is it okay to say "Also I did some modifications to..."?

Tags: grammar

I'm learning English right now and I have some questions about the usage of *"Also I.."* and *"Did some modifications"*

Is this sentence correct?, why?

Spanish is my first language, so I get some confusion with things like this.

Thank you.

Comment: Haven't seen the sentence, only parts. Where will you use these words, in an email? A report? You can add a comma after Also. *Made* some modifications sounds better.

Comment: Presumably you made some other comment(s) before using *also*, which we don't see.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with the following:

```
"Also, I made some modifications..."
```